# Re-Implement applet installer or applet deletion manager on javacard

Tags: smartcard, javacard, globalplatform

I know that the installer and deletion manager implemented already in the javacard. But I want to know if is there any way to implement them again in a new applet?

I mean, is the any way to write an applet that receives an AID and delete it?

Answer (score 0):

Only a Security Domain can install or uninstall Applets. Global Platform and Applet are strictly divided and Applets can only gain resticted and very limited rights from a Security Domain, e.g. changing the LC status. Read more in the Global Platform Specification